# Black screen in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've encountered a black screen problem in three.js. I've tried to add extra lights, change the background colour to another colour, but it does not work. If working properly, it should show a 3d model of singapore

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let scene, camera, renderer;
        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 2);
            hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 100);
            scene.add(hlight);
            const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333);

            scene.add(ambientLight);
            const topLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1); // (color, intensity)
            topLight.position.set(500, 500, 500) //top-left-ish
            topLight.castShadow = true;
            scene.add(topLight);
            wireframe:true
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
            
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            camera.position.z = 10
            let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load('singapore.glb', function(gltf){
                scene.add(gltf.scene);
            })
            
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        init();
        animate();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried by looking into many threads related to the same problem but to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Could it be that the model is there but it's very big or very small? Try opening your model in the three.js editor or the gltf viewer